# Operating on a file in java

Tags: java, file, search, logging, input

I'm having a bit of a problem with all the FileReaders and FileWriters in java. I want my program to get the name of the person and then after asking them a couple of questions evaluate their score. That is pretty easy but now what I want to do is to document it in a log file like this:

```
Jacob : 10
Mark : 15
Steve : 7
```

And then every time any of these people open the program it will retrieve their current score or if it is someone new it would append their name and score. 
I can't find a way to search a file and then retrieve the integer at the end.

EDIT:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    static Scores scoreClass = new Scores();

    private static void setupMap() {
        try {
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("scores.map");
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
            scoreClass = (Scores) ois.readObject();
          } catch (Exception e) {
              System.err.println("Could not load score data");
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
    private static void saveMap() {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("scores.map");
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
            oos.writeObject(scoreClass);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Could not save score data");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setupMap();
        int score = 0;
        String guess;
        String[][] questions_with_answers = {{"I __________ to school.(go)", "She __________ tennis. (play)", "She _______ a bitch. (be)"}, {"am going", "was playing", "is being"}};
        Scanner answer = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner studentInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is your name?");
        String name = answer.nextLine(); 
        if(Scores.getScore(name) == -1){
            Scores.setScore(name, score);
        } else {
            Scores.getScore(name);
        }

        System.out.println("Hello " + name + ". Your score is: " + score);
        for(int i = 0; i < (questions_with_answers[0].length); i++){
            System.out.println(questions_with_answers[0][i]);
            guess = studentInput.nextLine();
            if(guess.equals(questions_with_answers[1][i])){
                System.out.println("Correct! You get 1 point.");
                score = score + 1;
                System.out.println("Your score is " + score);
            } else {
                System.out.println("You made a mistake! No points...");
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("Congrats! You finished the test with "+ score +" points out of " + questions_with_answers[0].length);    
        Scores.setScore(name, score);
        saveMap();
        answer.close();
        studentInput.close();
    }
}
```

This doesn't throw any exceptions but still doesn't read the input from the file :/

Comment: What did you try so far? Show us some code

Comment: You can use in each line  `String [] array = line.split(":");` that would return an array, in your case if it was saved correctly , the size of the array should be 2. Then just use `int score = Integer.valueOf(array[1])`

Answer (score 0):

You could store the data as a hash map and then serialize it to a save file

I wrote an example that includes a class called Scores which has methods to read a score and add a score to a contained hash map. I also added methods in the main class for saving and opening a file that will contain the score class data.

Main Class:

```
public class Main {
    static Scores scoreClass = new Scores();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setupMap();
        //Do score calculations
        saveMap();

    }
    private static void setupMap() {
        try {
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("scores.map");
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
            scoreClass = (Scores) ois.readObject();
          } catch (Exception e) {
              System.err.println("Could not load score data");
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
    private static void saveMap() {
      try {
          FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("scores.map");
          @SuppressWarnings("resource")
          ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
          oos.writeObject(scoreClass);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          System.err.println("Could not save score data");
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

}
```

Scores Class:

```
public class Scores implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static Map<String, Integer> scoreMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public static int getScore(String name) {
        if (scoreMap.containsKey(name)) {
            return scoreMap.get(name);
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public static void setScore(String name, int score) {
        scoreMap.put(name, score);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for helping man :) still for some reason the score and the name doesn't read from the file :/ any idea as to why that could be?

Comment: Using the [java.util.Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class will take care of serialization for you :-)